# How can I join individual objects that have been texture painted and have them keep their individual paint scheme?

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders

I have created a wing model and each of the "feathers" is painted with a simple color ramp blend. When I join the whole, the entire wing takes on the blend. I have looked and all of the UV names for the individual "feather" objects is the same, so I can't just change the UV names, since they are already the same, yet I get this color shift every time I join them. Surely there is a way to maintain the individual look and have them joined, beyond the "make the UV names the same". Help is appreciated.

Comment: Hello could you please show some screenshots?